# how to create a batch file that will place another batch file in the startup folder

Tags: batch-file

i need to make a batch file, that, when ran, will place another batch file(that has been previously created and is in the same folder) in the startup folder of a non-specified users(%USERNAME% i think) computer.

I have tried various lines of code like this:

```
 COPY example.bat c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\windows\Start menu\Programs\startup

xcopy example.bat C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

move example.bat c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\windows\Start menu\Programs\startup
```

as you can see, I have no idea what i am doing.

I expect it to copy my bat file and place it into the startup folder.

when I run it, it does nothing, not even and error message

Comment: when a path/filename contains a space, you have to enclose it in quotes (good habit: enclose *all* paths/filenames in quotes): `COPY "example.bat"  "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\windows\Start menu\Programs\startup\"`

Comment: You shouldn't place files in the Startup folder, you should create shortcuts to files in there!

Comment: Compo, this is to be on a USB stick, therefore I have no idea what is in their startup, which is why I need to add files to their startup.

Comment: @Stephan excuse me for not knowing anything about this, but should I add example.bats' location in order for this to work?

Comment: the full path is not necessary (but doesn't hurt) when the file is in the current working folder.

Comment: @stephan i tried this code and the file did not appear in my startup. is there something i'm missing?

Comment: How could I know? I don't know, how your system is setup, I don't know what your (current) code looks like, I don't know how or from where you execute it, I don't know if there is an errormessage and what it says. Help us help you - keep in mind, we can't see your screen.